# Stack Overflow requires cookies for authentication -- are your browser cookies enabled for this domain?

Tags: support, cookies

When I try to use Firefox to create an account on Stack Overflow, it told me that

*"Stack Overflow requires cookies for authentication -- are your browser cookies enabled for this domain?"*

It works when I use IE, but I don't want to use IE.

**My Question:** How do I fix this?

Comment: Are [cookies enabled](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/949770) in your Firefox configuration?

Comment: See also [Network Login Troubleshooting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help).

Comment: To the downvoters: This is a legitimate question due to an apparent but in SO. When a user logs out, no new users can sign up until the cookies are manually cleared. When trying to sign up, they get this message despite the fact that cookies (and third-party cookies) are enabled in their browser.

Answer (score 6):

Clear your Cookies and Cache.

Go to *History* > *Clear Recent History...* >

A pop-up window will show up called *Clear All History*. Top of the window there is a list drop-box, choose *everything*, show *details* by clicking the side button, select Cookies and Cache, now press Clear Now.

Why do you have to clear the cookies?

You have to clear the old guest cookie that was stored before getting the new registered user cookie. And then you will be able to continue your registration for stackoverflow site.

All done.

Comment: How does clearing the cookies help store them for the domain?

Comment: You have to clear the old guest cookie that was stored before getting the new registered user cookie. And then you will be able to continue your registration for stackoverflow site.

Comment: You might want to explain that in the answer then.

Comment: @user3871993 did it actually work for you, or are you just guessing?

Comment: It worked for me about an hour ago and now am a registered user. So to answer your question, yes, it did work like a charm.

Comment: Its also works for chrome. I try it minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the following error message:

> Stack Overflow requires cookies for authentication -- are your browser cookies enabled for this domain?

You can try this:

- `For chrome`: Open a new browser window with new incognito window (Ctr+Shift+n).
- `For firefox`: Open a new browser window with new private window (Ctr+Shift+p)
- Go to sign up again.