# Migrated questions with a nonexistent author should still show the author's name in the questions list

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions, deleted-accounts, homepage

I just noticed [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188461/stack-overflow-requires-cookies-for-authentication-are-your-browser-cookies-e). Its author doesn't have an account on this site, which makes it show up like this on the homepage:

> [image: before]

It looks like a simple thing - but it gets in the way of the 'flow' of the page:

> [image]

Couldn't we *somehow* get the author's name, so that migrated questions with authors that don't have an account here still show up, like this:

> [image: after]

Much better. Please?

Comment: This likely has a technical restriction; it seems like nonexistent users can't show up on the homepage in any way whatsoever. For instance, when a user which existed at the time of activity is later deleted, the homepage changes to show the Community user instead.

Answer (score 3):

This oddity still happens, but for some reason I had never noticed it before. I was about to post it as a bug when I checked the archives and found this old feature request. So here I am, bumping the post.

The missing username is quite eerie, it should say something, **why can't the same  username  be visible on the home page?** You can read their username when you click on the question title and visit the page.

Maybe a placeholder such as “username”, “non-member” or “anonymous” at least until the user decides to join the site?

> [image]
>   **EL&U home page (Active)**

The original question was posted on [SE Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/posts/44725/revisions)