# Migrated question has the "ago" in last time of activity cut off from the right

Tags: bug, design, migrated-questions, homepage

A question was recently migrated from Literature to ELL, and when I went to check on it I saw this:

[image: "3 mins ago" has half the "o" cut off]

The final "o" in "3 mins ago" is a little less than half cut off. This seems to be an issue with [not having a user to display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188464/1017231), since all the last activity lines which have users involved are showing up properly.

If we can't get a user displayed for migrated questions, can we at least not cut off the last time of activity?

I'm running Windows 10 Home and version 91.0.4472.124 of Google Chrome.

Comment: (Unfortunately, anyone trying to reproduce this will have to find a different question, since someone answered the one pictured)

Comment: No longer reproducible with the new homepage format since the author name is now included for migrated questions.